# Is it OK to delete older versions of Windows 10 SDK?

Tags: windows, sdk, shared-libraries

I just installed the latest SDK(10.0.10586.0) and was wondering if I can delete the libraries from the older Windows 10 SDKs(10.0.10240.0 and 10.0.10150.0)?

Or is there a safe way or a program to do this?

Comment: I would expect that you can uninstall them via Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score 11):

You can uninstall the older versions via Add/Remove Programs. It maintains a different entry for each version.

Answer (score 11):

If  storage space is a pressing issue for you, you can proceed to delete the older SDKs. Deletion can be done via program files in pre Windows 10 Creators Update builds or from Settings in newer Windows 10 builds. 
However an ideal software should provide a good backward compatibility at least within a major version of Windows which at this point is Windows 10.

Imagine someone with an early build of Windows 10 being unable to download your app from the store. You lose users/customers just because they have to update their OS all the way which many avoid altogether.

Keeping the older SDKs will allow you choose a minimum Windows 10 build that your app should support and hence allow installation from devices on those builds.

Comment: Are you saying the newer SDK's are themselves not backwards compatible?

Comment: This is untrue. The Windows 10 SDK will target the Universal C/C++ Runtime, which is not OS specific. Anything built against any version of the Windows 10 SDK will run on Windows 8.1 & 10. Windows 8.1 might require a Windows Update, but it will work on all versions of 10.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes. It's almost like a sacrifice from my experience.

Comment: @JasonLocke 'will require an update' is the issue here. People will update apps but not everyone will update their OS because they want to install your app. My answer is very true and even more painful when I included Mobile for my UWP deployments.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to target specific builds of Windows, then you might want to keep older SDKs around. As new SDKs come out there may be functionality added that isn't supported by older builds of Windows, then your code will not run on that build. Generally you want to use the newest SDK available that works for your targeted audience.

Comment: You target specific versions by defining a macro in your project settings, not by using an old SDK.  "*The preprocessor macros `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` specify the minimum operating system version your code supports.*" See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

I have many versions and I am not sure which to delete. I found [How to move Windows Kits Folder to other disks?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb183507-74dc-466e-931b-7de110e73b20/how-to-move-windows-kits-folder-to-other-disks?forum=windowssdk) So if space is the problem then you can move the `Windows Kits` folder to another drive. That post says to move the `Windows Kits` folder to another drive and then with administrator privilges use the following:

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits" "D:\Windows Kits"
```

That creates a junction; joins the folder in the C: with the folder in the other drive.

Comment: Using "joining" as a term could be quite misleading. Otherwise: sound answer. I've been using this since junction points were introduced with Windows 2000. Vista symlinks are yet another form of reparse points, but require special privileges.